# What to use instead of "preload-webpack-plugin" with 5th and more version of the Webpack?

Tags: webpack, craco

I need to preload images. It was possible with "preload-webpack-plugin". But in 5th version of Webpack I faced with some problems. It seems to me that this plugin works with lower Webpack versions. Help me, please.

I tried to use script-ext-html-webpack-plugin instead, but I noticed that it does not support Webpack 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modern [html-bundler-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webdiscus/html-bundler-webpack-plugin#option-preload) to render HTML templates. This plugin can [preload](https://github.com/webdiscus/html-bundler-webpack-plugin#option-preload) everything without additional plugins.

Comment: is it possible to use it if my application was initialized with create-react-app? I want to use craco and some webpack plugin that allows to prelod

Comment: the plugin works with a custom webpack config for react, but not with config created with create-react-app, because the plugin replaces functionality many many plugins added via create-react-app. I haven't tested it with craco yet.

Comment: you can use as a boilerplate the simple example with React18, TS, SCSS: https://stackblitz.com/edit/webpack-react18-ts-scss

Comment: note: you not need the "preload-webpack-plugin", the html bundler plugin can self preload assets. The syntax of the `preload` option is the same, see please [preload option](https://github.com/webdiscus/html-bundler-webpack-plugin#option-preload)